# How to prevent bash for loop to transform string data

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to filter out datestamps from the message log and delete all occurances:
(basicly this is a part of an usb history cleaner script, head -n1 added only becouse of testing)

```
delimiter=`echo $HOSTNAME | cut -f1 -d.`

for item in `egrep usb /var/log/messages | awk -F"$delimiter" '{print $1}' | uniq | head -n1`; do
echo ${item}
done
```

when I run this command:

```
egrep usb /var/log/messages | awk -F"$delimiter" '{print $1}' | uniq | head -n1
```

the output is fine:

```
Mar 31 03:25:03
```

but when it will be given back to the for loop, the data transfers like this becouse of the spaces:

```
Mar
31
03:25:03
```

the question is: how can I prevent this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for item in `whatever`; do
echo ${item}
done
```

use:

```
whatever |
while IFS= read -r item; do
echo "${item}"
done
```

but your whole script could be re-written as just:

```
awk -F"${HOSTNAME%%.*}" '/usb/ && !seen[$1]++ {print $1}' /var/log/messages
```